# How to connect multiple Linux user on the same Linux server

Tags: linux, mount, credentials, multiuser

I have a server called CALCSRV used to run some big scripts from multiple USERS. Each user has on that CALCSRV a personnal HOME. Each user has his own Linux Computer. Each user can connect to CALCSRV with a ssh connection an his login/password to this CALCSRV.
When a user connect to the CALCSRV, the /etc/fstab file mount several directories from several other servers. BUT : the mount command in the /etc/fstab of CALCSRV require a credential file with login/password to mount the other servers. And I cant set a different credential for many users.

```
SERVER1 : IP 172.01.01.01
SERVER2 : IP 172.01.01.02

CALCSRV :
/HOME/user1
/HOME/user2
/HOME/user3

PC Linux of user1 : IP 172.01.01.101
PC Linux of user2 : IP 172.01.01.102
PC Linux of user3 : IP 172.01.01.103
PC Linux of user4 : IP 172.01.01.104
```

Each user connect to the CALCSRV by :

```
ssh user1@CALCSRV
ssh user2@CALCSRV
ssh user3@CALCSRV
```

and each user is in their own HOME at CALCSRV

CALCSRV /etc/fstab looks like :

```
//DATASERVER/ /mnt/DATA       cifs    auto,credentials=/root/.credentials    0       0
```

This way is not session dependant, there must be ONLY ONE credentials file but I have many users ! How to make a mount for each user with his own credential file ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

For a start you can't mount `/mnt/DATA` more than one time so you will have to create a mount point for every user. So why don't you put the mount command into each user's `.profile` with its own mount point and credentials?

Comment: Yes I thought about this solution but I dont want to give mount command to my users via visudo.

Comment: Your users should be able to mount this shares with `gvfs-mount` without sudo.

Comment: Thanx, i will try this